# Program adding same value to reach or exceed a given limit

Tags: python, loops

I would like to create a computer program that starts at a given value and adds the same sum over and over again in a loop until the total sum reaches or exceeds a given limit.

For example: I start at the number 7. I add 3 over and over again until the total sum reaches or exceeds x (the limit). If my limit is 23, the program would stop at 25 and display that it went beyond the limit by 2.

Comment: Which programming language do you intend to use? If you're not sure, [tag:JavaScript] is a good place to start.

Comment: I intend to use Python.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note that this is not a code-writing service or a tutorial service. We need a *specific question*, generally one that results from *your attempt to write the code*. If you are just starting with a language, you should try to learn it by *following a tutorial from the beginning*, and not worry about setting your own assignments - a decent tutorial will choose assignments for you, that are designed to reinforce the lessons.

Comment: Alternately: try to take things a step at a time. Can you write the code to "start at" a value? Can you write the code to add 3 to the value? Can you write the code to do something "over and over again"? Can you write the code to check whether the sum has reached or exceeded a limit? Can you write the code to stop repeating the task when that check is reached? Can you write the code to determine how far over the limit the resulting value is? Can you write the code to display a result?

Comment: Each task you don't know how to do yourself is a [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) topic, or a question to keep in mind as you work through a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

We have two kinds of loops in Python: for-loop and while-loop

Usually we use `while` when we don't know how many times we are going to do something...Here since you have a condition, and you don't know in advance how many times you have to add the value `3` to your `7` to reach the limit, it's time to use `while-loop`.

```py
initial = 7
add_value = 3
limit = 23

while initial < limit:
    initial += add_value
    
print(initial)
```

In every iteration, the condition (the expression you write in front of `while` keyword) is evaluated. If it evaluates to True, the body of the while block is gonna be executed, otherwise Python jumps out of the while-loop block and execute the next line after it.

I know you are particularly asking for loops but I just wanted to say that this question can be solved using simple math operations:

```py
initial = 7
add_value = 3
limit = 23

d, r = divmod(limit - initial, add_value)
if r == 0:
    print(initial + add_value * d)
else:
    print(initial + add_value * (d + 1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your very quick response. Gonna check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using while-loop as follows:

```py
start = 7
end = 23
add = 3

while start <= end:
    start += add

if start == end:
    print(“Ended at end value”)
else:
    print(“Went beyond the limit by: ”, start-end)
```

Here, in while-loop, we check if the start value reaches or exceeds the limit using `<=` . When that’s not the case, the add value is added to the start value. When it reaches or exceeds it, the loop ends. If the program reaches exactly to the limit, it prints that “Ended at value”. Otherwise, it prints “Went beyond the limit by: X”.

Comment: if you use `<` instead of `<=`, that takes care of the rest. Then you don't need to have `if start == end` condition

Comment: Yes, I wanted to simplify it more as OP has explicitly asked to show by how much it exceeded the limit.